# Div to bitmap image? NodeJS / WinJS / anything?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, bitmap, winjs

Is there any way to convert a div to an image that the user can save without using other languages.
I've looked everywhere but I can't seem to find any way to render html to bitmap , not even in nodeJS or WinJS.
There are a lot of applications that could benefit from this , any reason why this can't be done without a server?

Comment: To do that, you need a browser (more specifically, an HTML renderer).  Look at PhantomJS or wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: As @SLaks mentions Node can do screenshots through PhantomJS; WinJS can also do screenshots, but I don't think you can restrict it to a given `<div>` element.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 8.1 you can load the HTML into an [x-ms-webview element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301831.aspx) using its navigate or navigateToString methods, then use the webview's [capturePreviewToBlobAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301835.aspx) method. (If you have a div, you might be able to get its innerHTML string and pass to the webview's navigateToString to load that content.)

Note that this isn't WinJS specifically, as this is a feature of the webview element. So it might not be a solution that's portable to the web generally.

In any case, here's a code snippet from an example in Chapter 4 of my free ebook ([Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, Second Edition](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2)) that captures a webview's contents into a bitmap which it then displays in an img element (notice how I turn the DOM-ish async call into a WinJS promise for convenience):

function captureImage() {
       var webview = document.getElementById("webview");

```
    var promise = new WinJS.Promise(function (cd, ed) {
        var op = webview.capturePreviewToBlobAsync();
        op.oncomplete = function (args) { cd(args.target.result); };
        op.onerror = function (e) { ed(e); };
        op.start();
    });

    promise.then(function (blob) {
        document.getElementById("imgOutput").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob, { oneTimeOnly : true });
    });
}
```

You can do whatever else you want with the blob that the promise delivers, e.g. write to a file, upload, etc. But that's how you can get the rendering in Win 8.1.